# Linphone - getting SDK

Tags: cocoapods, linphone

I'm trying to follow the instruction for Linphone, to download the SDK for iOS, either here:

https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Lib/Getting%20started/iOS/

or here: https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-iphone

They both start with this CocoaPods thing, that im not familiar with, and it doesn't seem to work... all I get is this error:

```
[!] Couldn't determine repo type for URL: 'https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/podspec.git': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3 column 17
```

Tried on Mac M1, and Intel Mac. Always the same error. I would rather not build the entire SDK, just need to include the SDK in my project.

Answer (score 0):

To include the sdk you need to place a source to their podspec git in the pods file and then you can use it as if it was in cocoapods

Example ios pod file:

```
source ‘https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/podspec.git’
source ‘https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git’
platform :ios, ‘11.0’target ‘test’ do
    project ‘test.xcodeproj’
    pod ‘linphone-sdk’, ‘~> 5.0’
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed for iOS since some months.
I have forgotten to fix this also for MacOS podspec repo.
This is now also fixed.

The explanation is here : https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-sdk/issues/207

TL;DR : It was an issue caused by Gitlab's way to handle files not found (redirection) for Cocoapods-version.yml, confusing Cocoapods.